# How to detect this kind of scratch of below image with opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, graph-algorithm

[image: result]

Guys how to detect this kind of scratch with opencv ? I tried the thresh and adaptiveThreshold but both couldn't find the scratch area. Can somebody please give me some advice. Thanks.

Comment: What actually characterises that scratch? That it is longer than the others? That it is not parallel to the others? Something else?

Comment: first of all you get an image that doesn't look that aweful. it will make much easier. crap in -> crap out

Comment: I mean the vertical line which is not parallel to the others.

Comment: So the line you seek is always vertical? Maybe you could provide additional examples?

Comment: It would be great if you provided two images: One that shows how the image without stratches looks like and the one that contains scratch without any added contents (such as red ellipse). If you can provide more than one image that has scratch, even better!